# MathF.Clamp issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following a tutorial in C# and Unity and i have deviated a little off the code, I was hoping someone could help me understand how to add a MathF.Clamp to my code.

```
var delta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

transform.position = new Vector3(
transform.position.x + delta.x,
transform.position.y + delta.y,
transform.position.z);
```

All advice is welcome. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish. "add a `MathF.Clamp`" doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: I am trying to stop my sprite/player from moving out of the screen.

The instructor was setting up a boundry system using the camera and ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,0)).x //for the min x position.

Comment: Are you still using an orthographic camera?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an orthographic camera, you can still use `Mathf.Clamp` and `ViewportToWorldPoint`. You'll just need to use it for each component. You can get the min and max for the x and y together by using `ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,0));` and `ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,1,0));`.

Altogether, this might look like this:

```
private Camera mainCam;

Start() 
{
    // Camera.main calls FindGameObjectsWithTag internally, which is a costly operation.
    // It's best to cache the results of Camera.main when possible to save on computation.
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}

Update()
{
    var delta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 
            Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

    Vector3 minPos = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,0));
    Vector3 maxPos = mainCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1,1,0));

    transform.position = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + delta.x, minPos.x, maxPos.x),
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y + delta.y, minPos.y, maxPos.y),
    transform.position.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep your camera in bounds using `Mathf.Clamp`. You have to define the min and max values where the camera is allowed to move:

```
var delta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),
    Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

transform.position = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + delta.x, minX, maxX),
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y + delta.y, minY, maxX),
    transform.position.z);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
var delta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),
    Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

transform.position = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + delta.x, minX, maxX),
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y + delta.y, minY, maxX),
    transform.position.z);
```